# Cross Domain Ajax Call Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am trying to call a page with ajax, but from another server. This js code runs from bookmark in any page you want and I need to get some data from my server. How could  I do this? or maybe connect directly to the database?

I got this code:

```
$j.getJSON(serverUrl+"isLogin.php?callback=?",function(data){
 //really no need to do anything here, we're just posting data
 //but this will output success
 alert(data);
});
```

isLogin:

```
if ($_SESSION['user'] == ''){
     echo json_encode(array("isLogin" => "false"));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array("isLogin" => "true"));
}
```

How could I make this? I try allot of solutions but none works. This one said no errors, but the alert never appear

Thanks

Comment: Cross domain isn't supposed to work for security reasons, maybe try an external JS file from the server itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX (The XMLHttpRequest object) is limited to the same domain for security reasons.

You have a couple ways to go about this:

You can use JSONP if your API supports it.  This is very similar to your current AJAX approach.
This is jQuery's documentation - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Another option is to create a local proxy.  This is a little more in depth, but gives you full control. 
Here's a good article - http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: If the server is configured correctly to allow it, and the client supports it, then XHR2 can be used with its Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-cors